# Change tel: handler on El Capitan Mac OX

Tags: macos, mac

I'm going nuts trying to figure this one out. 
Currently, tel: links from a web page open Facetime but I would like it to open Skype instead.

How can I do this?
RCDefaultApp, the most suggested app from the 2009 doesn't even show up in the applications list or the system preferences after installation, so not sure what else I need to do?

Thanks!